# Odoo Custom Button in Tree View

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I follow developer tutorial from Odoo documentation and I found that we can make a custom button like check and cross button.

[image]

But the problem is, I can't found the source code to achieve those features. How can I add those custom buttons?

Comment: Just use fontawesome classes on buttons. Both "Smartbuttons" (big buttons with value in it) and list buttons are already useful with odoo look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple class that you can use on buttons times for cross and check for ticks

```
<button name="function_for_button_press" type="object" class="fa fa-check" />
<button name="function_for_button_press" type="object" class="fa fa-times" />
```

also use style tags to make them look better
[list of icons you can use in odoo](https://www.slideshare.net/TaiebKristou/odoo-icon-smart-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

In odoo backend form I usually use:

```
<button name="action_check" type="object" icon="fa-check text-success" string="Check"/>
<button name="action_cross" type="object" icon="fa-times text-success" string="Cross"/>
```

`text-success` it is for icon's green color.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.